# Facebook Android SDK ProfilePictureView caching

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using `ProfilePictureView` class to display profile pictures. It takes a bit of time to request these images and display them. In a ListView with multiple profile pictures, then it will clearly take even longer.

Has anyone a pattern to cache these pictures so that they are only fetched every once in a while?

As far as I can see, the Facebook Android SDK does not have any in-built caching mechanism for this type of thing (correct me if I'm wrong, I hope).

I would be interested in hearing other developers solutions to this problem, even if it means moving away from the `ProfilePictureView` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide to move away from the ProfilePictureView, you have a few options in terms of loading and caching images in a ListView.

The first one, LastList, I've personally used in several projects and it works very well:  https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

This second one I have not used, but I believe works on the same premise.
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader